# Nested forms with Showmodal in Win32/OSX

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7, multiplatform

I have a situation where I have 3 forms. I open `Form2` from `Form1` and `Form3` from `Form2`

`Form2` is shown as ModalForm, `Form3` is not.

When I run this project in **Windows**, I can switch between `Form2` and `Form3` but I cannot go back to `Form1` before I close `Form2` (as expected).

In **OSX**, `Form3` is opened behind `Form2` and cannot be accesed(not expected) until I close `Form2`.

What is the usual design philosophy for Multi-platform projects?

Should I always open Childform in same state as parentform if the parentform is Modal?

Comment: You say the behavior is "as expected" in Windows, but what appears in OSX is NOT. But perhaps this IS "expected" behavior in OSX. I'm trying to wrap my head around why I'd want to open a non-modal form from a modal form, b/c when you close the modal form, the state of its (non-modal) child form could be left undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd set this up where the non-modal form (`Form3`) is opened from the main form (`Form1`). That way, there's no question about its parentage. I'd put a method into `Form2` that's initialized from `Form1` after it creates `Form2` but before it calls `ShowModal` that `Form2` uses to open `Form3`. Include any parameters in the call that `Form2` needs to pass into `Form3`.

This approach eliminates the explicit circular reference between `Form1` and `Form2` and keeps `Form3` independent of `Form2`.